# discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.fun' raised an error: IndentationError: expected an indented block (fun.py, line 7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

when I attempted to make a cog (keep in mind I'm new to making cogs) I get the error

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.fun' raised an error: IndentationError: expected an indented block (fun.py, line 7)
```

the code for the cog is;

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

class Fun(commands.Cog):

    def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(Example(bot))

        def __init__(self, bot):
            self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Cog is up!')

        @commands.command
        async def ping(ctx):
            await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured out the answer, you need to put a set up module in all of your cogs. If you don't do that it'll give you the error if you want to load everything at the bot start.

Comment: What is a setup module?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that your `setup()` function is inside the `Fun` class, instead it should be outside so it can be called. So in your case it would look like:

```
import os  
import discord  
from discord.ext import commands

class Fun(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Cog is up!')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Fun(bot))
```